# Новые значения старых слов

Tags: лексика

Когда и где  за  малолетним  ребёнком  закрепилось  слово  "мелкий" ?  По  крайней  мере  в  прошлом  веке  я  в  таком  значении  этого  слова  не  встречал.

Comment: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/811481-pochemu-detej-nazyvajut-melkimi-vashe-otnoshenie.html

Answer (score 3):

Из толкового словаря русского школьного и студенческого фольклора (2005 год).

Мелкий.
1. Шк.Ученик младших классов: Для мелких будет утренник, а это дискотека, чувствуешь разницу? (Запись 2001 года).

2. Студ. (ист.) В. И. Ленин: А про мелкого что говорить? - Спросите сначала у препода, а то обидишь чувака. (Запись 2003 года).

Comment: Правильно все, только фиксация явно более поздняя. Словарная фиксация всегда отстает лет на десять, а то и более. В данном случае - лет на двадцать, думаю.

Comment: Не является ответом. Да и Вопрос изначально был другим: автора не только «когда и где» интересовали, но и «что».

Answer (score 1):

Это такое же просторечие, как "правильный" по отношению к чему-то предпочитаемому. Мотив - попытка уклониться от избитых выражений (младший, маленький и пр.). Закрепилось на том же основании, что "мелко-мягкие" при ссылке на "Майкрософт", и имеет столь же ограниченное применение. Книгу такими выражениями не напишут.

Answer (score 1):

Закрепилось слово «мелкий» на уровне не выше среднего в средней возрастной группе, в средней школе в значении армейского или матросского — *салага*. Там бы ему и остаться. И время его перерождения из прилагательного — середина 90-х. До той поры бытовали мелкие *собственники*, *мошенники*, *жулики*, *воришки*, *интриганы*, *мелочь пузатая*, *мелочные расчёты*, *мелкотравчатость*, *мелкая рыбёшка* и тот, кто *мелко плавает*. Так что в череде одиозных  и уничижительных понятий существительное *мелкий*, определяющее возраст, стало в известном смысле реабилитирующим явлением. Но осадок остаётся.

Comment: По  времени  появления  выражения  вполне  согласен.  А  по локализации  возникновения  есть  какие-нибудь  представления ?  Мне  почему-то  кажется,  что  это  питерское  выражение.  Но  настаивать  не  берусь.

Comment: Слово прозвучало на всю страну без какой-либо локализации в первых сериях «Большой перемены». Там про Нестора Петровича было сказано: мелкий, но ужасно умный. 1972 год.

Answer (score 0):

Первое упоминание в словаре - 2002 год:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Другие](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) (из того, что удалось обнаружить) - более поздние:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама я впервые услышала "мелкий" от понаехавшего-тут компьютерного мастера-рвача лет десять назад (не спросила, откуда он), а дочь утверждает, что слышала в Питере году так в 1997-м...

Comment: "Мелкий ребёнок" - ужасное "смятение сапогов". Это вне стиля употребления нео-существительного "мелкий". Ребенка это приравнивает мелкому чиновнику :)

Comment: Alex_ander, мне тоже не нравится ответ Galina Avanesova, но в одном могу и Вам возразить. Да, это смешение стилей, но это **умышленное смешение**. И как раз этим определяется его стиль. А Словарь, на который Г.А. ссылается - это как раз словарь арго, жаргонизмов.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, это довольно давнее использование. Слышано едва ли не в детстве как вполне обычное и распространенное. Видимо для разделения "маленький" (по возрасту и по размерам). Еще есть "малой", которое "мелким" сейчас вытесняется.

По сравнению с "малым" мелкий гораздо емче, ведь в одном из значений "мелкий" - незначимый, незначительный, "Мелочь пузатая". Видимо это и определяет популярность.

Comment: Незначимый разве не то же, что несущественный? Это о ребёнке-то! И ещё. На вопрос «Когда?» отвечено: Давно, едва ли не в детстве. Но ведь не об относительно времени вашего детства Вопрос.

Comment: Ну мое детво прошло в СССР. Явно не 200-какй-то там, как тут пророчат. А незначительный - да, близко к несущественный. А вас старшие братья-сестры-приятели всегда всерьез воспринимали?

Comment: Тяжёлый случай. Простите.

Comment: Да нет. Все вполне нормально.